# Symfony2 ManyToMany or OneToMany or what?

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm trying since about 2 weeks to get my code running.

Database structure (simplified):

**Table User**
| ID | Username |

**Table Tasks**
| ID | Task Title | Task Type |User

**Table Task Type**
| ID | Task Type Title |

**Table Task Done**
| ID | Task ID | User ID

**What I want:**

add a Task, select if task is global ( visible for every user) or if task is visible for just one user ( global or User-ID is put into table field "User" in Table "Tasks".

If I marked a task as "done", I want to make an entry into the table "Task Done" with the task ID and user ID ( user ID's value comes from the page, where the entry is done, normally its the same value as in table "Tasks" field "USER" , but when the task is a "global" task, the value for "USER ID" in table "Task Done" can't be "global" but the ID of the User, who is working this task.

I tried many ways with many to many, one to many and so on. But I always get errors, can someone help me? I have read, that there could be some problems with the table field names for the "ID" field.

Maybe someone can tell me how to setup the database structure / entites. 
It would help me a lot!

Kind regards,
Marvin

**EDIT 1**

Error while doing doctrine:schema:update --force in console.

```
[Doctrine\DBALDBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE tasks ADD CONSTRAINT
FK_50586597BF396750 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES task_done (id)':                                                                 

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`seotool`.`#sql-382_38`, CONSTRAINT `FK_50586597BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `task_done` (`id`))

[PDOException]    
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`seotool`.`#sql-382_38`, CONSTRAINT `FK_50586597BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `task_done` (`id`))
```

**Code Task.php**

```
<?php

 namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="tasks")
  */
 class Task {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $task_title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $task_description;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $task_priority;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaskTypes", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tasktype", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $TaskTypes;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $User;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaskDone", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $TaskDone;

....
```

**Code TaskDone.php**

```
<?php

 namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="task_done")
  */
 class TaskDone
 {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="TaskDone")
 */
protected $task;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

.....
```

Comment: What is your code / error you are getting?

Comment: I've added the exception from the console and the code snippets of Task.php and TaskDone.php

Comment: Looks like you might have some ids in the task Table that are pointing to non existing TaskDone records. Could you check for such mismatches?

Comment: My TaskDone Table is empty, because no Task is Done. When I mark a Task as "done" , the system adds an entry into "TaskDone" with the ID of the user and the id of the task, which was marked. But the task itself doesnt change in the Table "Tasks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn´t recreate your exact error but looking at your disired table structure I got an example running by changing the name of the join column... your were asking doctrine to create a column used as a foreing key but the table already contains a column named id. Use something like name="task_ id" instead.

you have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaskDone", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $TaskDone;
```

change it to this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaskDone", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $TaskDone;
```

You also have the relation backwards. This will create a filed task_id in your "Task" table and you wanted to create it in the "Task Done" table. To fix this you should place the OnetoMany on the Task Entity and the ManyToOne in the TaskDone.

[Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)